# Error on launching app in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I successfully installed my application in my blackberry but on running it gives an error:

```
Error starting MyApp:Module Myapp atempts to access a secure Api.
```

I want to run this app on my device.Please suggest a way to run my app.

Comment: i am not able to sign my app how am i supposed to do that.I also created other apps which did not require signing.My app ran properly in the simulator however

Comment: if you want to run app on device, you have to sign your app. Else it will not work on device.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-and-When-to-Sign/ta-p/442779

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the app is not signed. Get your keys from here:

https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

In order to sign the file, make sure you have the three signing files available on your system (RBB, RCR and RRT). In order to sign an app, the files first need to be included:

BlackBerry (located at the top) -> Sign -> Install New Keys

Once the keys are included in your project, sign your app:

Right Click project -> BlackBerry -> Sign with Signation Tool. It will prompt for a password which is what you created when getting your keys.

Once the app is signed, load your project:

Right Click project -> BlackBerry -> Load Project on Device

Make sure your app has no compilation errors in order for the app to package successfully.